# Click event is not firing of dynamically added link button in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing the following code on the rowdatabound of the grid view and i am not getting the click event of link button

```
Protected Sub CoolGRDSourcedDetails_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles CoolGRDSourcedDetails.RowDataBound
        Dim iLoop As Integer
        Dim lbtnCountDetails As New LinkButton
        e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1)
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            For iLoop = 1 To (dscolumns / 2) - 1
                e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Attributes.Add("colspan", "2")
                If iLoop = 1 Then
                    e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text = "Self"
                Else
                    e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text = "Child" & iLoop - 2
                End If
            Next
            e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text = "Total"
        ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            For iLoop = 1 To dscolumns - 2
                If iLoop Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                    e.Row.Cells(iLoop + 1).Text = Format(IIf(CInt(e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text) <> 0, (CInt(e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text) / value) * 100, 0), "0.00") & "%"
                    If CInt(e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text) <> 0 Then
                        e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Controls.Add(lbtnCountDetails)
                        lbtnCountDetails.Text = e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text
                        lbtnCountDetails.CommandArgument = "strstatus"
                        lbtnCountDetails.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "lbtnCountDetails_Click")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

'Click event is here

```
Protected Sub lbtnCountDetails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim strStatus As String = CType(sender, LinkButton).CommandArgument
    End Sub
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx That might be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the below line in your code and make changes after that: -

```
ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
```

Actually you forgot to add an event handler to the event of LinkButton1, so you are not able to get the click event of the LinkButton.

The changes you have to make : -

```
If CInt(e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text) <> 0 Then
                            LinkButton1.Text = e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Text
                            AddHandler LinkButton1.Click, AddressOf Me.LinkButton1_Click
                            LinkButton1.CommandArgument = e.Row.Cells(0).Text
                            e.Row.Cells(iLoop).Controls.Add(LinkButton1)
                        End If
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the event binding with an Attributes.Add. You can use the [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event from the gridview. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx) has a good example of using RowCommand.
Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351169/dynamic-buttons-in-gridview-button-click-event-not-fireing).

Answer (score 0):

Give a command name to your link button, like this

```
CommandName="Show"
```

and in the code behind, handle it as,

```
    protected void gridviewReport_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Show")
        {
            // this will return the row index
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            // your code goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
 Dim WithEvents lbtnCountDetails As New LinkButton
```